In surreal numbers, what are the main difficulties so far in defining integration?
I know, there were several (including unsuccessful) attempts at defining integration on surreal numbers, so I am asking for a good summary of what have been the main difficulties so far.
Particularly,

Why one cannot assume that Newton-Leibnitz formula still holds on surreals, and so do symbolic integration of functions and then find defined integrals from Newton-Leibnitz formula? Or it in fact works but does not provide enough generality and does not cover all desired cases (bad-behaved or surreal-valued functions under integral, etc)?

Are the current theories of surreal integration concerned with surreal-valued expressions under integral at all? If so, why they cannot simply re-use the theory of distributions and theory of hyperfunctions apparatus for the purpose, which looks straightforward for me.

Are the current theories of surreal integration aimed at providing symbolic finding of integrals or do they seek the answers in the $\{L|R\}$ form or as a series or in another form, what is the main target? Or the main difficulty is in having numbers in $\{L|R\}$ form as integration limits?

Is the main difficuly of foundational and justificational character rather that in obtaining symbolic solutions?


P.S. At @TimothyChow's encouragement, I made a paper on proposed theory of surreal integration.

If you think you have a satisfactory theory of integration on the surreals, then I recommend that you write it up properly as a preprint, especially if your theory has some features that others consider counterintuitive. In a preprint, you can take the necessary time to explain the merits of your theory, as well as why the counterintuitive properties are features and not bugs. Scattershot comments and questions on MO are not going to get you very far.

A preliminary answer that should really be a comment, but it's too long; everything I'm about to say is better explicated in

Integration on the Surreals, O. Costin, P. Ehrlich, 2024, arXiv:2208.14331

which is soon to appear in the journal Advances in Mathematics. Philip is also a member of the community here, and will likely explain all of this better than I can. Any errors in what follows are mine.

Newton-Liebnitz gives the wrong answer when integrating $e^x$ on the surreals.

Extensions of real-valued functions are a primary focus, however this paper more generally studies resurgent functions, a subclass of smooth functions that contains the functions that at ∞ are semi-algebraic, semi-analytic, analytic, meromorphic, and Borel summable as well as solutions to nonresonant linear and nonlinear meromorphic systems of ODEs or of difference equations.

$\{L|R\}$ definitions of integration are called genetic in the literature; various genetic definitions have been explored, however the final definition the authors arrive at in this paper is not genetic if I've understood things correctly.

As indicated in the final portion of the abstract and in section $13$ of the paper, there are foundational difficulties in extending this definition of surreal integration to the class of all smooth functions.



Thanks. Is there an example of how and why Newton-Leibnitz fails on surreals? Are not resurgent functions a subset of real valued functions?

I believe the section titled "Difficulties of defining extensions and integration of functions, and our strategy for overcoming them" beginning on page 14 addresses the questions you're asking -- reading papers yourself is part of research! ;^)

I have just looked into the paper and the property (b) in Proposition 14 seems completely unjustified to me. But this is a substance for another question...

This property seems to be the source of all the troubles: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/475902/why-is-the-property-of-linearity-against-an-infinitely-large-factor-considered-e

This post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94998/integration-in-the-surreal-numbers?rq=1 says that defining integration using Riemann sums gives wrong answer for $\exp(x)$ but where it is shown that Newton-Leibnitz formula gives a wrong result (if used after symbolic finding of the indefinite integral)?
